# How to find if all the columns in a dataframe are object dtype?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a DataFrame as `data`, and I want to find if every single column in the data frame is an object and use it as an if condition.

example:

```py
describe = data.describe
(if condition to find all the columns are 'object'):
  agg = data.agg(['a','b','c'])
  if not agg.empty:
    describe = pd.concat(describe,agg)
    describe = describe.round(2)
```

Comment: please provide an explicit and reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not without ambiguity, but you probably want to combine[`dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html), [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html):

```
if df.dtypes.eq(object).all():
    # do something
```

Another option:

```
if df.select_dtypes(exclude='object').empty:
     # do something
```

Comment: just wrote an example, kindly refer to that

Comment: @Dhruv can you provide a dummy `data` for reproducibility? I believe my solution should already work (using `describe` in place of `df`)

Comment: i will try it but do i need to use any '==' in the condition, like `if df.dtypes.eq("object").all() == "object"`

Comment: @Dhruv no the `eq` is already `==` (you could write `(df.dtypes == object).all()`)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.dtypes`

here's the example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5,2,3], 'B':['a','b','c']})
```

```py
>>> df.dtypes

A     int64
B    object
dtype: object
```

and if you want to find all object column names

```
>>> [k for k,v in dict(df.dtypes).items() if v == object]

['B']
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.info()` or `data.dtypes` will give you overall statistics of columns.

If you want the datatype of each column in one command do `dict(data.dtypes)`

---

```
for x in data.columns:
    if data[x].dtype == object:
        #do something
```

Comment: I want to use the code for an if condition, let's say if all the columns are objects than does not concat() else do it.

Comment: Please provide complete dataframe with the code you have tried.

Comment: added an example in question

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
#get all columns by dtypes == object
print (df.select_dtypes('object'))

#processing only object columns - here call describe
agg = df.select_dtypes('object').describe()

#default describe omit non numeric columns
describe = df.describe()

#joined together
out = pd.concat([describe,agg], axis=1)
```

Or:

```
out = df.apply(lambda x: x.describe())
```